# Placeholder for part of HTTP GET param in Retrofit?

Tags: java, http, get, annotations, retrofit2

Trying to build @Get annotation upon Retrofit2 interface method:

```
 @GET("select?q=DH_PROD_ID:{journalId}")
    Call<PdhResult> getJournal(@Path("journalId") String journalId, Callback<PdhResult> resultCallback);
```

This variant causes an error:

```
URL query string "q=DH_PROD_ID:{journalId}" must not have replace block
```

And as you can see here, query param q has constant and variable parts.

Due to several reasons it is undesired to build full value of param outside for every call.

I just want `journalId` replaced with provided `String journalId`, is it possible?

Comment: Do you remember what you ended up doing with this? I'm having the same problem today.

Answer (score 0):

How about defining the method like

```
@GET("select")
Call<PdhResult> getJournal(@QueryParam("q") JournalId journalId, Callback<PdhResult> resultCallback)

class JournalId
{
    String id;

    public JournalId(String id)
    {
        if (id == null || !id.startsWith("DH_PROD_ID:"))
        {
            //throw proper exception
        }
        this.id = id.substring("DH_PROD_ID:".length());
    }

    public String getId()
    {
        return id;
    }
}
```

Comment: Unfortunately, there are several methods with this issue and it will produce much additional code